# For em objeto no typescript, como pegar o nome do objeto?

Tags: angular, typescript

Estou realizando uma estrutura de repetição para verificar quais campos do meu formulário estão invalidos. Preciso pegar o nome do primeiro campo que está inválido.

Tentei algo como:

```
for(var campoObrigatorio in formulario.controls){

  if(formulario.controls[campoObrigatorio].status == "INVALID"){
    var displayCampoObrigatorio = formulario.controls[campoObrigatorio];
    console.log(displayCampoObrigatorio)
    return ;
  }

}
```

Aparentemente minha lógica está correta, porém não estou conseguindo pegar o nome do objeto nessa linha:

```
var displayCampoObrigatorio = formulario.controls[campoObrigatorio];
```

Aqui ele pega toda a arvore dom do campo que está com o status invalido, eu gostaria do nome do objeto. Ex: altura, comprimento, etc...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O nome de cada uma das `keys` é `campoObrigatorio`

```js
const objetos = {
  a: {
    prop: 1
  },
  b: {
    prop: 2
  }
};

for (let nome in objetos) {
  console.log({
    nome,
    conteudo: objetos[nome]
  })
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, troquei por console.log(campoObrigatorio) e consegui o resultado que eu precisava.